# Multiselect component label as number

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am using this component https://github.com/vueform/multiselect

```html
<Multiselect :options="testData" label="name"/>
```

```js
 const testData = computed(() => {
      return [
        { name: 'Vue.js', id: 'vue' },
        { name: 'Angular', id: 'angular' }
      ]
 })

return { testData }
```

The label have to be a property from an object. Anyone knows, if it's possible for the label to look like `1, 2` instead of `Vue.js, Angular`? I want the label to be displayed as numbers. Like `index + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use map on the array:

```js
...
[...].map((value, index) => {
  return {
    name: value.name,
    id: index+1
  }
})
...
```

[Check this example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)